# How do I disable CGN (LSN) so I can host a server?

Tags: ipv6, nat, ipv4, hosting

I have figured out that inbound packets do not reach my home network due to an apparent existence of CGN. This fully inhibits my ability to host a server. I have set up everything correctly; port forwarding and the like, so I am quite positive that the issue is not related to any wrongdoings of mine. I have heard something about deploying IPv6 to bypass the "third layer" of CGN, but I do not know for sure if this will fix the issue. Please fill me in with any insight you may be able to offer.
Cheers.

Edit:

I use Telstra, and so does my friend. He uses the same residential plan  that I do, and he can host servers fine. The only difference is that he claims that he doesnt have a router or modem. I now have a hint of doubt that CGN is actually the cause here.

Comment: You can't. Talk to your ISP

Answer (score 3):

CGN is something your ISP does, not something you can change. And the ISP often doesn't have a choice because they don't have enough IPv4 addresses to give every customer a separate one. So they have to make customers share addresses through the use of CGN.

You might be able to convince your ISP to give you your own public address, but you probably would have to pay extra for it. And in many cases the ISP just doesn't provide it at all anymore.

IPv4 runout is nasty, which is why everybody should implement IPv6 everywhere. It's the only solution we have to get out of this IPv4 mess...

Comment: So you're saying, that implementing IPv6 will solve the issue?

Comment: In the long run, yes. The problem is that it only works if everybody else has IPv6 as well, which is not the case yet.